# Connect with database but still nothing happens

Tags: php, mysql

I have just uploaded my web site for testing with my friends on 000webhost and i have an issue when I m trying to signup/login it works to send data to mysql database, in the table `users` it shows that the X is logged in, with password etc, but in my website it doesn't show the content that supposed to show when the user is connected and the login form doesn't change to logout form. I don't know how to describe better.. In my localhost it works perfectly!

I've been searching for 2 days for response, I still found nothing. 
Here's the index.php that supposed to change when I'm logged in:

```
session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['userId'])){
        echo ' <nav>
        <ul class="nav-links">
        <li><a href="portfolio.php">Design Area</a></li>
        <li><a href="uploads/upload.php">Upload</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="menu-phone">
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
    <form class="box" action="login/logout.php" method="post">
        <button class="btn-logout" type="submit" name="logout-submit">Logout</button>
    </form>
    <p class="info-log-in">Connected</p>
    </nav>';
    } else {
        echo '
        <nav>
        <form class="box" action="login/login.inc.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="mailuid" placeholder="Username/E-mail..." class="text-login">
        <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password..." class="text-login">
        <button class="btn-login" type="submit" name="login-submit">Login</button> 
        <a class="btn-signup" href="signup.php">Signup</a><p class="or">OR</p></nav>
        </form>
        <p class="info-log">Disconnected!</p>
        ';
    }
```

And the login.inc.php

```
if(isset($_POST['login-submit'])){

    require 'dbh.inc.php';

    $mailuid = $_POST['mailuid'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];

    if(empty($mailuid) || empty($password )){
        header("Location: ../index.php?error=emptyfields");
        exit();
    }
    else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE widUsers=? OR emailUsers=?;";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
            header("Location: ../index.php?error=sqlerror");
            exit(); 
        }
        else {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $mailuid, $mailuid);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $pwdCheck = password_verify($password, $row['pwdUsers']);
                if($pwdCheck == false){
                    header("Location: ../index.php?error=wrongpassword");
                    exit();
                }
                else if($pwdCheck == true){
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['idUsers'];
                    $_SESSION['userUId'] = $row['widUsers'];

                    header("Location: ../index.php");
                    exit();
                }
                else {
                    header("Location: ../index.php?error=wrongpassword");
                    exit();
                }
            }
            else {
                header("Location: ../index.php?error=nouser");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
else {
    header("Location: ../index.php");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Are you even setting the value of `$_SESSION['userId']` once a user logs in ?

Comment: There's a lot of code missing here. Based on the bit of code you have shown us, I'd have to guess that you are not setting the value in your session. Can you show the code that takes the user login and creates the session?

Comment: I just posted the login.inc.php, but why in my localhost is working?

Comment: Your code does not check for any error messages, nor does it display any debugging information, so your are completely in the dark as to why your code does not work.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: @Shadow but why in my localhost it s working properly?

Comment: @Hiddenache without debugging information it is impossible to tell why it does not work. It may be as simple as pointing the MySQL connection to the right database. The whole point is: if you do not debug, we are in the dark and we cannot really help you.